# In what point a Repeater differs from DataList web-server control?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, datalist, databound-controls

They are both data bound controls. They both have template related features. Can you explain in what point Repeater differs from DataList web-server control? And when one should be picked to be used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice difference explanation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa479015

Comment: DataList is the control that allow you Repeat-Columns horizontally or vertically

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you need to layout a list where each item represents a cell in a grid you would go for a data list.

Think of a product catalog, where each item is displayed in a cell, instead of covering the full row of the grid.

If you want the item to spawn across the entire row, like Stackoverflow questions, you would use the repeater (or any other list control).

Hope it helps!